# I want to get the edge of the mask in python, which will be used for labels in deep learning loss function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

Mask example:
[image: Mask example]

Mask edge example:
[image: Mask edge example]

This is my current code, which takes a long time to process the data.
I want to speed up this process, thanks!

```
    for b_index in range(masks_np.shape[0]):
        for s_index in range(masks_np.shape[1]):
            imageio.imwrite('./mask_seg_vis/'+s_number+"_"+str(s_index)+str(b_index)+'.png', masks_np[b_index][s_index][0])
            unique_values= np.unique(masks_np[b_index][s_index][0].reshape(-1))
            mask_edge = np.zeros(masks_np[b_index][s_index][0].shape)
            for v_index in range(len(unique_values)):
                itemindex_1 = np.where(masks_np[b_index][s_index][0] == unique_values[v_index])
                itemindex_0 = np.where(masks_np[b_index][s_index][0] != unique_values[v_index])
                v_mask = copy.deepcopy(masks_np[b_index][s_index][0])
                v_mask[itemindex_1] = 255
                v_mask[itemindex_0] = 0
                for x in range(v_mask.shape[0]):
                    for y in range(v_mask.shape[1]):
                        if v_mask[x][y] == 0:
                            continue
                        if x == 0 or y == 0 or x == v_mask.shape[0]-1 or y == v_mask.shape[1]-1:
                            continue
                        if v_mask[x-1][y] == 255 and v_mask[x+1][y] == 255 and v_mask[x][y-1] == 255 and v_mask[x][y+1] == 255:
                            continue
                        mask_edge[x][y]=255

            imageio.imwrite('./mask_seg_vis/'+s_number+"_"+str(s_index)+str(b_index)+'_edge.png', mask_edge)
```

Comment: why you don't use pre-existent edge detection algorithms such as [Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) instead of the loops??

Comment: Thanks, Bilal. I did not know Canny before, and I will try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get nearly the same result using Canny edge detection in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('mask_grays.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# do canny edge detection
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 0,0)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mask_grays_canny.png', canny)

# show results
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Canny Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. In my case, where I can get access to the ground truth masks, do you think the best values for the low&high threshold of the Canny function are 0&0?

Comment: I found that some details are missing when I set low and high thresholds to (50,100) or (0,100). So, I guess (0,0), in my case, fits my brute force code the best?

Comment: For your type image, you need 0 and 0 to get all the lines.